# How can i display image stored in mobile device on my aplication?

Tags: c#, image, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an aplication where at some point i need to acess user's contacts list and get data from there. For this i used `Xamarin.Forms.Contacts(1.0.5)` plugins and it worked well. I was able to get `Name Number Email PhotoUri PhotoUriThumbnail` from each contact. And then i display some of the infos on my aplication. However, i am not able to display image from `PhotoUri` directory. `PhotoUri` is a string with this format : `content://android/...`. I tried converting `PhotoUri` to `ImageSource` and then use it on xaml file but nothing worked... Can anyone help ?

Comment: Can you check your contacts’ image folder path on android like emulated/0...

Comment: Do u want me to show PhotoUri string ? Please be more specific

Comment: PhotoUri = "content://com.android.contacts/display_photo/1"; PhotUriThumbnail="content://com.android.contacts/contacts/33327/photo"

Comment: I mean in android file system users stored profile photo path not your photo uri

Comment: I dont know how to reach that path

Comment: Are you using emulator or device ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190496/discussion-between-kelve-and-batuhan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting data from a `content://` URI, you can use the `ContentResolver`. Specifically you can load the contents from the file with `ContentResolver.OpenInputStream` ([see here](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Content.ContentResolver.OpenInputStream/p/Android.Net.Uri/)). To display the image you could use a `StreamImageSource` ([see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.streamimagesource?view=xamarin-forms)). Given you already have an `Uri`, you can instantiate the `StreamImageSource` as seen in the following snippet

```
var contentResolver = Application.ApplicationContext.ContentResolver;
var streamImageSource = new StreamImageSource() 
{
    Stream = (cancellationToken) => Task.FromResult(contentResolver.OpenInputStream(uri));
}
```

*Please note*: If `PhotoUri` is note derived from `Android.Net.Uri` you'll have to convert it to the latter.

#### Edit

The code presented works from `MainActivity`, only. As an workaround I've added an static property `Instance` to `MainActivity` that is assigned in `OnCreate`

```
public static MainActivity Instance { get; private set; }

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    this.Window.RequestFeature(WindowFeatures.ActionBar);
    this.SetTheme(Resource.Style.MainTheme);

    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

    MainActivity.Instance = this;

    // whatever
}
```

you can then use

```
var contentResolver = MainActivity.Instance.Application.ApplicationContext.ContentResolver;
```

which might not be optimal, but works. Alternatively (which I'd prefer) you could inject the `MainActivity` to your instances.

#### Edit 2

Since the question arose how to use this code from Xamarin.Forms, I'll give a short outline. If you're not using dependency injection, the easiest way will be using `DependencyService` (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction)). Create an interface in your shared code

```
public interface IContentLoader
{
    ImageSource LoadFromContentUri(Uri uri);
}
```

The implementation of this interface has to be added to the platform project

```
[assembly: Dependency (typeof (Droid.ContentLoader))]

namespace Droid
{
    public class ContentLoader : IContentLoader
    {
        public ImageSource LoadFromContentUri(Uri uri)
        {
            var contentResolver = MainActivity.Instance.Application.ApplicationContext.ContentResolver;
            var streamImageSource = new StreamImageSource() 
            {
                Stream = (cancellationToken) => Task.FromResult(contentResolver.OpenInputStream(Android.Net.Uri.Parse(uri.ToString())));
            }
            return streamImageSource;
        }
    }
}
```

Now the `IContentLoader` can be used from your Xamarin.Forms project using the `DependencyService`:

```
var contentLoader = DependencyService.Get<IContentLoader>();
// ...
var imageSource = contentLoader.LoadFromContentUri(uri);
```

**Please note**: If you are programming for iOS *and* Android, you'll have to take care that you can load your images from both platforms.

Comment: Hi, i get error saying that Application has no member named ApplicationContext

Comment: Sorry, this works only from an `Activity`, give me a minute.

Comment: but i need the image just for 1 page, and that page is not the main page. Still getting error :(

Comment: Yes. But i assume that your code is for xamarin.android. I am using xamarin.forms and when i try to use this function on shared project, i get error.

Comment: Of course. There are ways to implement access to platform facilities. I’ll add another edit later.

Comment: Thanks for helping and for the patience. I'll accept the answer as correct but i still am getting an error. Could u check this https://ibb.co/qDsX70V to see the error ? its a print screen.

Comment: And contentLoader is null after this `DependencyService.Get<IContentLoader>();`

Comment: I've edited the final snippet. Of course I’d necessary to use the static `MainActivity.Instance` I have introduced in my first edit. About the `null`: Did you add the `Dependency` attribute from my snippet? I can’t see it in your screenshot.

Comment: Thank you sooo much! You saved my day :D. Also thanks again for being patient